# Writing to a proxy using a socket and returning response to client

Tags: java, sockets, http, proxy

I'm trying to create a proxy server in Java that rotates proxies. What I mean is, I am creating a proxy server that passes on the request to another random proxy, gets the response from that random proxy and returns it back to the client.

Something like this:

- Client Request -> My proxy server
- My proxy server -> random proxy server
- random proxy server -> My proxy server
- My proxy server -> Client

I have 2 main classes handling this. The first class is called `RunnableRequestLayer` and it is responsible for reading the client's request, and sending the response back. The second class is `RequestMaker` which connects to a random proxy, and has a `send()` and `receive()` method which send/receive from the random proxy.

Here is the relevant code from both classes:

Class #1: `RunnableRequestRelayer`

```
public class RunnableRequestRelayer implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    private final int maxTries = 5;

    public RunnableRequestRelayer(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket; //This socket is the serverSocket.accept() socket
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Got a request!");

        try(
                PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                ){

            RequestMaker rm = new RequestMaker();
            int tries = 0;

            while(tries++ < maxTries){
                try{
                    rm.connect();   
                } catch(IOException e){
                    continue;
                }

                String inputLine;

                //This while loop reads the input HttpRequest fine.
                while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                    if(inputLine.equals(""))
                        break;

                    rm.send(inputLine + "\r\n");
                    //System.out.println(rm.receive());
                }

                System.out.println("Test"); //This is successfully printing.


                String outputLine;
                //This output loop is never entered... why?
                while((outputLine = rm.receive()) != null){
                    System.out.println("In output loop");
                    if(outputLine.equals(""))
                        break;

                    out.print(outputLine + "\r\n");
                    out.flush();
                    System.out.println(outputLine);
                }

                rm.disconnect();
                tries = maxTries;
            }

        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Bad");
        }

    }
```

Class #2: `RequestMaker`

```
public class RequestMaker {

    private Socket socket;

    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    public void connect() throws IOException {
        String[] proxy = ProxyGenerator.generate().split(":"); 
        socket = new Socket(proxy[0], Integer.parseInt(proxy[1]));

        System.out.println("Connected to proxy - " + proxy[0] + ":" + proxy[1]);
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    }

    public void send(String s) {
        out.write(s);
        out.flush();
    }

    public String receive() throws IOException {
        return in.readLine();
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try{
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close(); 
        } catch(IOException e) {}
    }

}
```

I tried testing this with fiddler too. I set the proxy to connect to `127.0.0.1:8888` which is Fiddler's proxy server. Once again, the request was received from the client, but the proxy on Fiddler never received it.

My question is: Why is the while loop that reads from the proxy not entering in the first place? I checked if the rm.receive() was returning `""` or `null` using an if, and it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was not following the HTTP protocol properly. Had to send an empty line after writing the input request to the proxy server.